# Translate Python for loop into a while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How could the function that takes a list of numbers, `[1,2,3`], return the list `[3,2,1]` by using a while loop instead of the provided for loop. Also, what do the excessive -1's mean in the for loop.

```
def for_version(items):
   result = []
   for i in range(len(items) - 1, -1, -1):
      result.append(items[i])
   return result
```

Comment: Isn't items.reverse() suitable for you?

Comment: Yeah, but we needed to write the code to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excessive `-1` in the `range(len(items) - 1, -1, -1)` are, in order, the lower bound of the sequence (in case of negative step) returned and the step ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)).

For example, `range(5, -1, -1)` means *list of numbers from 5 down to 0 (-1 is the exclusive boundary), step down by 1*.

As to the while loop:

```
def while_version(items):
    i = len(items) - 1
    result = []
    while i >= 0:
        result.append(items[i])
        i -= 1
    return result
```

The `i` variable simulates the results of `range(len(items) - 1, -1, -1)`.